# How do I translate this SQL statement in R? Basically, I want to see the the english authors who are older than 40 years in R. Thank you

Tags: sql, r, postgresql

```
select *
from autors
where ((current_date- interval '40 years')> dateofbirth) and 
(country like 'England%')
```

Comment: It is difficult to help you since you don't provide exemple of your dataset in R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

data = tibble(autor = "William Morris", 
              dateofbirth = as_date("1834-03-24"), 
              country = "England")

data %>%
 filter(lubridate::interval(dateofbirth, Sys.Date())/years(1) > 40 & 
        country %in% c("England"))

# A tibble: 1 x 3
  autor           dateofbirth   country
  <chr>           <date>        <chr>  
1 William Morris  1834-03-24    England
```